# Simplfying expression to get $b-a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\left( \frac{2a}{3}+\frac{b}{3} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{b-a}{4} \right)b^0 = b-a$$

I know that $$\left( \frac{2a}{3}+\frac{b}{3} \right)^0 = 1$$

and $$\left( \frac{b-a}{4} \right)b^0=\frac{b-a}{4}$$

but then how do I simplify the rest to get the solution which Is $b-a$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=b-a$. Then don't you simply have $$\frac 34 t+ \frac 14 t=t$$ which is blatantly obvious?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\left( \frac{2a}{3}+\frac{b}{3} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{b-a}{4} \right)b^0 = b-a$$
$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\cdot1+\left( \frac{b-a}{4} \right)\cdot1=b-a$$
$$\dfrac{3b-3a}{4}+\dfrac{b-a}{4}=b-a$$
$$\dfrac{4b-4a}{4}=b-a$$
$$b-a=b-a$$

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my question

Answer (score 0):

The equation becomes $$
\frac{3}{4}(b-a) + \left( \frac{b-a}{4} \right) = b-a \\
\frac{3}{4}(b-a) + \frac{1}{4}(b-a) = b-a \\
b-a=b-a
$$

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my question

Comment: I don't think the typo has been fixed.

Comment: fixed, thanks!!